# MarkLogic is losing my line breaks in .xqy files when inserting via curl PUT

Tags: marklogic

Anytime I add an `xquery` script using `curl`, the resulting file on the server loses all page breaks and some whitespace. This causes lines to run together and some words to run together.  This is causing the script to fail due to reserved words getting concatenated with others.

The command I'm using is this:

```
curl --anyauth --user username:password -X PUT -d @"./badactorasset-lib.xqy" -i -H "Content-type: application/xquery" http://localhost:8004/v1/ext/badactor/badactorasset-lib.xqy
```

When I browse other .xqy files on the MarkLogic server through the Query Console, those file display with lines breaks perfectly.  The files I add are all missing line breaks and look unreadable.

***Example of another file that was loaded in the past on to the server:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace ba = "http://marklogic.com/badactor/badactor";
declare option xdmp:mapping "false";
declare variable $ba:ETYPES := ("HX", "FER", "RER", "ELEC", "INSTR");
declare function ba:get-duration($type as xs:string) as xs:yearMonthDuration
{
  let $years :=
    if ($type eq "HX") then 5
    else if ($type eq "FER") then 10
    else if ($type eq "RER") then 2
    else if ($type eq "ELEC") then 10
    else if ($type eq "INSTR") then 2
    else 0
  return xs:yearMonthDuration("P" || fn:string($years) || "Y")
};
```

***Example of my file on the server:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";module namespace ba = "http://marklogic.com/badactor/badactorasset";declare option xdmp:mapping "false";declare variable $ba:ETYPES := ("HX", "FER", "RER", "ELEC", "INSTR");declare function ba:get-duration($type as xs:string) as xs:yearMonthDuration{  let $years :=    if ($type eq "HX") then 5    else if ($type eq "FER") then 10    else if ($type eq "RER") then 2    else if ($type eq "ELEC") then 10    else if ($type eq "INSTR") then 2    else 0  return xs:yearMonthDuration("P" || fn:string($years) || "Y")};declare function ba:get-threshold($type as xs:string) as xs:integer{   if ($type eq "INST
```

What am I missing? Why are my files losing their structure?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue deep in some documentation unrelated to MarkLogic.

I should use the "`--data-binary`" flag instead of the default "`-d`" flag  in order to preserve line breaks.  This isn't discussed on MarkLogic's site or in any of their examples, but it fixed my files.

Here's the full curl command now:

`curl --anyauth --user username:password -X PUT --data-binary @"./badactorasset-lib.xqy" -i -H "Content-type: application/xquery" http://localhost:8004/v1/ext/badactor/badactorasset-lib.xqy`

Comment: Generally, XQuery is not sensitive to the removal of newlines in the way that JavaScript and SPARQL are, so your code should work regardless. Be that as it may, the use of --data-binary to preserve newlines is mentioned here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/intro#id_73954.